# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError, Running unit tests in VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, testng

I am trying to run some Java unit tests from VSCode, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception occured while running tests.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.testng.TestNG.addListener(org.testng.ITestNGListener)'
    at com.microsoft.java.test.runner.testng.TestNGRunner.run(TestNGRunner.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.java.test.runner.testng.TestNGLauncher.execute(TestNGLauncher.java:32)
    at com.microsoft.java.test.runner.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:57)
```

My tests are written with TestNG, I have the following extensions installed in VSCode, any ideas what might cause the error?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)